# INSERT IF NOT EXIST

Tags: mysql, sql

seems pretty simply but ive tried everything i can find on here and just keep getting an error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;

every time a user visits the page i want to update a table called range_views

```
INSERT INTO range_views (range_id, ip_address, view_date) values('112','123.123.123.123','2015-02-01')
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM range_views 
               WHERE range_id = '112'
               AND ip_address = '123.123.123.123'
               AND view_date = '2015-02-01');
```

the table has 4 columns

```
id - AUTO_INCREMENT
range_id - INT(6)
ip_address - VARCHAR(15)
view_date - VARCHAR(10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an `UNIQUE INDEX` on columns `range_id`, `ip_address`, `view_date`:

```
ALTER TABLE range_views
ADD UNIQUE INDEX id_ip_date(range_id, ip_address, view_date);
```

You need this index anyway; it will enforce your rule of adding new entries only if the value of (`range_id`, `ip_address`, `view_date`) pair does not already exist in the table.

Then `INSERT` the values and add `IGNORE`:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO range_views(range_id, ip_address, view_date) 
VALUES('112','123.123.123.123','2015-02-01');
```

The [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html) says:

> If you use the `IGNORE` keyword, errors that occur while executing the `INSERT` statement are ignored. For example, without `IGNORE`, a row that duplicates an existing `UNIQUE` index or `PRIMARY KEY` value in the table causes a duplicate-key error and the statement is aborted. With `IGNORE`, the row is discarded and no error occurs. Ignored errors generate warnings instead.

Comment: thanks for that!! i tried the INSERT IGNORE previously but it just kept inserting a new record regardless!

Answer (score 4):

This syntax is invalid. You have to rewrite it with the syntax `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`, something like this:

```
INSERT INTO range_views (range_id, ip_address, view_date) 
SELECT '112', '123.123.123.123', '2015-02-01'
FROM range_views
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM range_views 
                 WHERE range_id = '112'
                   AND ip_address = '123.123.123.123'
                   AND view_date = '2015-02-01');
```